# How to get an specific item in a NSOutLineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I am currently playing with the SourceView example from Apple.

As a task I wanted to change the menu at the bottom of the application into a context menu on right click. Now I have implemented a `NSMenuDelegate`and using the `menuWillOpen` method to make my adjustments in the menu.

The problem I face now is that I can not get information about the object I right clicked in the tree.

I got the index of the item but I can not get the item itself.

```
NSInteger *clickedRow = [myOutlineView clickedRow];
```

I tried this, but it does not give me anything.

```
ChildNode *item = [myOutlineView itemAtRow:clickedRow];
```

I hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you determine the `clickedRow`?
One thing that seems to be wrong is, that you are storing the `clickedRow` in an integer *pointer* (NSInteger*) instead of an integer.
So `itemAtRow:` possibly uses an arbitrary address instead of the actual row index to lookup the item.
Another thing is, that `itemAtRow:` returns an `NSTreeControllerNode*` and not a `ChildNode*` as you are assuming.
You should use

```
[[myOutlineView itemAtRow:clickedRow] representedObject];
```

instead

Comment: - (NSInteger)clickedRow; comes natively from NSTableView. I just stored it in my own variable for convenience.